# Checking if a Scala List is of class List

Tags: scala

I'm trying to test an object to check and make sure it is indeed a List. This is in a unit test, and I'm using scalatest `assertResult` to check like so:

```
val result: Option[List[String]] = Some(List("A", "List"))
assertResult(classOf[List[String]], "the class should be List of Strings")(result.get.getClass)
```

This compares `result.getClass` to `classOf[List[String]]` and checks equality that way. However, it turns out that `result` is actually a `::` as evidenced by the error message from scalatest:

```
Expected class scala.collection.immutable.List, but got class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon the class should be List of Strings
```

How can I truly check to see if its a `List`?

Comment: `("a" :: "b" :: Nil).isInstanceOf[List[String]]`?

Comment: It's one of those days, I totally forgot that was the way to compare classes...

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I was just going to suggest the same, one problem tough is that `.isInstanceOf[List[String]]` can only check the **List** part, but not the **String** _(I would even write it `.isInstanceOf[List[_]]` just to make the code clearer)_ - if skylerl needs to check also the **String** part, then you may need to use `TypeTag` - However, does not the compiler already checks this?, or your value is actually of type `Option[Any]` ?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Ah... Yeah, you're of course right. The `isInstanceOf` has the same problem as `classOf[List[String]]` - it will also erase types. I'm not sure what the OP is trying to do, actually. Type checking should usually be left to the type checker at compile time... Maybe it's an XY-problem?

Comment: [anInstance mustBe a<Type>](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_matchers#checkingAnObjectsClass) doesn't seem to help with type erasure either. Other suggestions?

Comment: If anyone has better suggestions, I think it would be better to add a new answer to the linked duplicate.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin & skylerl I just posted an answer on the linked question for this specific case. Hope it helps! - BTW, I tried to make something more generic using `TypeTags` but failed miserable.